# Why is given temperature greater than saturation temperature, but given pressure is less than saturation pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics

Water is at 150 kPa and 200C. Using steam tables, I determined that the saturation temperature of water at 150 kPa is 111.35C. This must mean that the water is superheated. However, when I look up the saturation pressure at 200C, the given saturation pressure is 1554.9 kPa, which leads me to believe that the water is a saturated mixture. How do I determine whether the water is a saturated mixture or superheated vapor at this temperature?

Comment: I don't see how, at 150 kPa and 200 C, you can think that it is  saturated mixture.  It is clearly at a pressure less than its saturation vapor pressure, so it is clearly superheated (by both criteria).

Comment: Where did the values of 150 kPa and 200 deg C come from?

Answer (score 0):

@David White Do you have a problem with steam being in this superheated state?

[image]